# Sql select distinct in a firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird

SO I have this firebird database and I am trying to select the users with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fi_GEBRUIKER1 FROM BANDZENDINGEN
```

I use razorsql. but DISTINCT is colored red, I assume this means I am doing something wrong.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

EDIT

oke it just worked, but it took about 200 seconds and if I try it on my website my webiste crashes with this error message:
        ERROR 503 - Service Unavailable!

Comment: Your query looks fine. Doesn't it return the expected result?

Comment: what is the `PLAN` of your query? do you have index on `Fi_GEBRUIKER1` field ? What data type that field is? also, can you make another table, a dictionary where values in `Fi_GEBRUIKER1` would only be included once, and there would be integer ID, and then you remove the field from `BANDZENDINGEN` altogether and instead add there a link to that new table (integer `id_gebr` that would be a `foreign key` to the new table?)

Comment: Pterhaps try to read Grabber's "essential SQL" and some tutorials about data storage and access and on "relational databases" in general. And by tutorials I do not mean some FAQ, but a good practical book 300-500 pages size. With focus on general principles no less than on any specific programs and buttons in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT is a statement  used to return only distinct (different) values as it is reserve word so your editor show it in different color it does not mean wrong

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fi_GEBRUIKER1 FROM BANDZENDINGEN
```

your query is fine it will work

Comment: thank you it tried it, it work it just took very long (about 200 seconds) and if i try this with php my website crashes with ERROR 503 - Service Unavailable!